# Client-side classes structure in UML project

Tags: java, uml

I and two university colleagues of mine are designing a simple CMS software for a university exam using UML. Such software just needs to deal with sending an article, assigning an article for review, sending a review and scoring an article. Our solution expects a 3-tier client-server architecture, with tiny clients requesting services and a server responding to requests by interfacing with a DBMS (persistent data) and a SMTP server (e-mail notifications).

I'm at a point where I can't decide how to structure my client-side classes. I figured out a set of *boundary* classes representing single services and contain related methods (authentication, submit paper, review paper...), and a single *control* class which roles are requesting connection to the server and the creation of a new session, and it contains the methods to actually send messages to the server.
This is according to the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) that states that any class should be responsible over a single functionality of the software: so, I have a class for signing up/logging in, one to submit an article, and so on, and then the *control* class that receives requests from other *boundary* classes and send messages to the server.

[image: Client requests are sent to the server via a control class]

On the other hand, I was told by other people I asked that I could even get rid of my client-side *controller* class and give *boundary* classes methods to directly send request messages to the server. This still seems legit to me: *boundary* classes only send requests according to the particular service they were supposed to provide to the user.

Question is: is having a *control* class in my client application useful, redundant, or wrong at all? How can I improve my classes structure?

Comment: Well, as always: it depends. You can get rid of your client controller, but at what cost. Look at your browser. It received more and more controllers you don't notice. When you type in Google search it interacts. And clients get faster each day. So what's the point in removing it? To strip it to 74xx logic bricks?

Comment: You have tagged this question with "java". Does this mean that the client-side classes will be Java classes? Do you have any constraints on the client-side technology to be used, like libraries / frameworks? Based on functional and non-functional requirements, you should choose the technologies and libraries first. This choice will probably give you a direction with regard to the client software design.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl No costrains about technology, nor frameworks. Libraries include JavaMail, Swing, JDBC-ODBC, and the socket library. These packages are included but not shown in my figure because I'm focusing on application classes rather than components.

Comment: I don't have experience with Swing, but I know it is based on the MVC pattern. When applying this pattern, I would expect one controller per view. In addition, I would expect one extra controller to encapsulate the messaging over the socket for all views, like ctrClientManager, which is responsible for creating the socket, the message streams and other message-related plumbing, to avoid code duplication in the boundary classes.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl So what you mean is I may have e.g. a set of _boundary_ classes for services related to X activity, and another one for Y; every group of classes talks to a _control_ class, so that I get two controllers, one for X and one for Y; finally, a super _control_ class that manages the other specific controllers and deals with connectivity, is that right? I like it, though I have a new question now: is having many classes either messy or bad engineering?

Comment: No, the quality of software is not correlated to the number of classes. Good quality means that every class has a well-defined responsibility, that different concerns are separated in different classes and that code is not duplicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question is: is having a control class in my client application useful, redundant, or wrong at all? How can I improve my classes structure?

It is useful. Your controller, ctrClientManager, encapsulates the messaging over the socket; it is responsible for creating the socket, the message streams and other message-related plumbing. Every boundary class needs this functionality and it would lead to **code duplication** if every boundary class would directly send messages.

*It improves maintainability*, because if something needs to be changed generically in the communication between client and server, you can do that at a central place (the controller) instead of adapting each and every boundary class.

*It improves reliability*, because the chance that there is a bug in one central piece of code is less than the chance that there is a bug in one of the many copies of the same code.

By the way, it is recommended to apply the MVC pattern, where each view (boundary class) has its own controller, to control the user interaction. In addition, you should have the central messaging controller, called ctrClientManager in your example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and your advices, I'll deepen knowledge about MVC pattern in order to better structure my system.